# creating a makefile for 2 targets

Tags: makefile

gcc 4.4.1
C99

I am creating a client server application.

I have a Makefile that compiles all the files. However, I would like 2 create 2 targets (binaries) one called clt and svr. And would like the Makefile to create 2 separate directories for them, called ./client and ./server?

So far I have done this to my Makefile. That only creates the svr. I am not sure how I can add the second target for the client to be created.

Hope you understand my point?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

```
OBJECT_FILES = server.o client.o cltsvr_ults.o

CFLAGS = -ggdb -Wall -pthread

LIBS = -lpthread

CC = gcc

svr: $(OBJECT_FILES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECT_FILES) $(LIBS) -o svr

client.o: client.c cltsvr_ults.h
    $(CC) -c client.c

server.o: server.c cltsvr_ults.h
    $(CC) -c server.c

cltsvr_ults.o: cltsvr_ults.c
    $(CC) -c cltsvr_ults.c

clean:
    rm svr *.o *~
```

Comment: "Makefile" doesn't compile anything and it doesn't create any directories.  **It is just a file!**  What invokes compiler and `mkdir` commands is `make` program, which gets your Makefile as an input.  So, fixing tagsl see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24030/why-do-they-specify-makefile-tag-instead-of-make/26567#26567

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't explained how to make clt, what objects go into it. And the list of objects for svr looks odd-- should it really have client.o? I will assume that clt is made of client2.o and cltcvr_ults.o. This makefile should do what you want, including making the directories:

```
SVR_OBJECT_FILES = server.o client.o cltsvr_ults.o
CLT_OBJECT_FILES = client2.o cltsvr_ults.o  

CFLAGS = -ggdb -Wall -pthread
LIBS = -lpthread 
CC = gcc  

all: client/clt server/svr
client/clt: $(CLT_OBJECT_FILES) 
server/svr: $(SVR_OBJECT_FILES)  

client/clt server/svr:
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ $(LIBS) -o $@  

client.o client2.o server.o: cltsvr_ults.h  

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $<  

clean: 
    rm -f client/clt server/svr *.o *~
```

Comment: "makefile should do"... "makefile... do"... *sigh*

Comment: Oh come on Pavel, a Makefile is code, like a script. Is it really so bad to say "this Makefile does X", instead of "this makefile casuses make to do X"?

Answer (score 4):

Make your first (default) target depend on the `clt`and`svr` targets.

```
all:  svr clt

svr: ...
clt: ...
```

You also will want to have the `clt`and`svr` target create the subdirectories.

Another, probably better, approach is to move all the server code into its own directory, and likewise all the client code into its own directory. (This assumes that you can split the code nicely into two portions.) Then have a small Makefile in the top directory whose targets execute the Makefiles in each of the subdirectories.

**Addendum**

You make the top Makefile invoke the Makefiles in the subdirectories by coding rules like these for each subdirectory:

```
clt:  cd clt; make $(MAKEFLAGS)
svr:  cd svr; make $(MAKEFLAGS)
```

This spawns a subprocess to perform another `make` in the `clt` directory, and another `make` subprocess for the `svr` subdirectory.

Comment: That sounds like a better idea. However, how can my top directory call the 2 makefiles in the sub-directories? Thanks.

Comment: By doing a `cd clt; make $(MAKEFLAGS)`, which spawns a subprocess to perform the sub-make. Ditto for the `svr` target.

Answer (score 3):

You can put your dependency graph for `clt` in there as well and add a first rule like this:

```
all: svr clt
```

Comment: Yep.  One point - make looks for the first target by default, so place "all" above the "svr" and "clt" targets.

Comment: Hence *first* rule. But yes, I could have made that point clearer, I think.